# Package MemoryMapState does not exist

Tags: apache-storm, trident

While compiling Storm Trident topology using maven error occurs as

> package MemoryMapState does not exist

Comment: Which Storm version you are using to compile your code? and post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

solved this problem. Actually there is no import for memorymapstate.